# Using routes, have route/component do an ajax call on route change?

Tags: angular

I'd like to have an ajax call done on each route change, that loads data into the current route's component scope.

I've done this in Angular 1 using controllers and events. When a controller gets loaded, do the ajax request, wait for response, then continue on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on getting started with something like this for Angular 2?

Comment: Oh.. there's legitimate component inheritance now... Let me see where that leads...

Comment: Do you mean you want to make an async call, and wait until it is resolved before changing routes? There is a resolver: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html. See if this helps.

Basically it lets you preload something before the route is changed and it is stored in the route snapshot so the proceeding component has access to it.

Comment: Yeah. I basically want to inject a service into every "page" component. This looks promising....

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

Answer (score 0):

I've created a base Component that all pages extend. When the component is created, in the constructor I assign the service to a private variable, and on the ngOnInit I run the service to get its data.

```
export class BasicPageComponent implements OnInit {

  protected pageService: PageDataService;
  protected data;
  protected options;

  constructor(public key:string) {
    this.pageService = ServiceLoader.injector.get(PageDataService);
  }

  getData(): void {
    if(!this.key) { return; }
    this.pageService.get(this.key).then(data => {
      this.data = data.data; 
      this.options = data.options;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

}
```

And then a child component:

```
export class GeneralComponent extends BasicPageComponent {
    constructor() {
        super("general");
    };
}
```

And then my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PageDataService {
  private pageUrl: string;
  private currentPage: PageData;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.pageUrl = environment.url;
  }

  get(query: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set("q", query);
    options.search = params;

    return this.http.get(this.pageUrl, options).toPromise().then(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if(error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.log(errMsg);
    return Promise.reject(errMsg);
  }
}
```

This seems to work well.

Now I just need to figure out how to get the data exposed into a template...